# Fitting of mpmath.zeta using scipy.optimize.curve_fit with bounds encounters NaNs

Tags: python-3.x, curve-fitting, least-squares, scipy-optimize, mpmath

This is a follow-up of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76092797/error-when-trying-to-pass-bounds-to-scipy-curve-fit). More information, including actual working example, can be found there. After doing some research I decided to post a new question rather than edit the previous one.
I have written a python script that performs a fitting of the function based on `mpmath.zeta` to the experimental data, using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`. When I try to pass the `bounds` to `curve_fit`, I encounter the following error:
`ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`
Without the bounds, code excecutes and returns some (sometimes even reasonable) results.

I have tried to trace the error through the source code of [curve_fit](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.10.1/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py#L549-L912) and [least_squares](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.10.1/scipy/optimize/_lsq/least_squares.py#L241-L963). The error occurs in the line 836 of [least_squares](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.10.1/scipy/optimize/_lsq/least_squares.py#L241-L963), which writes:

```
if not np.all(np.isfinite(f0)):
    raise ValueError("Residuals are not finite in the initial point.")
```

It means that `np.isfinite(f0)` gets the parameter type it cannot handle. The parameter `f0` is a `np.array` type, and `type(f0[1])` returns `<class 'mpmath.ctx_mp_python.mpf'>`. After re-defining `f0 = np.array(f0).astype(float)`, the error dissapears, but I don't want to modify the source of `least_squares`. Here is what I've figured out so far:

1. `least_squares` is called by `curve_fit` in the following way:

```
least_squares(func, p0, jac=jac, bounds=bounds, method=method, **kwargs)
```

with
`p0 = np.array([10, 50, 10, 1]) # my initial guess for parameters`
`bounds = (np.array([0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0]), np.array([2500.0, 2500.0, 2500.0,1000.0])) # my bounds for fitting parameters`
2. `func` is defined by `curve_fit` as `func = _wrap_func(f, xdata, ydata, transform)`, where

```
def _wrap_func(func, xdata, ydata, transform):
    if transform is None:
        def func_wrapped(params):
            return func(xdata, *params) - ydata
    elif transform.ndim == 1:
        def func_wrapped(params):
            return transform * (func(xdata, *params) - ydata)
    else:
        # Chisq = (y - yd)^T C^{-1} (y-yd)
        # transform = L such that C = L L^T
        # C^{-1} = L^{-T} L^{-1}
        # Chisq = (y - yd)^T L^{-T} L^{-1} (y-yd)
        # Define (y-yd)' = L^{-1} (y-yd)
        # by solving
        # L (y-yd)' = (y-yd)
        # and minimize (y-yd)'^T (y-yd)'
        def func_wrapped(params):
            return solve_triangular(transform, func(xdata, *params) - ydata, lower=True)
    return func_wrapped
```

with `xdata, ydata` being my experimental values, and `f` - function that I pass to `curve_fit`
3. In my case,

```
def f(B, l, lfi, lso, N):
    q = 1.602*10**-19 #elementary charge in Coulomb
    h = 6.626*10**-34 #Planck constant in J*s (NOT hbar!)
    hbar = h/(2*np.pi) #reduced Planck constant
    
    lb = np.sqrt(hbar/(4*q*np.abs(B))) #magnetic length
    
    l = l*10**-9
    lfi = lfi*10**-9
    lso = lso*10**-9 # characteristic coherence lengths of the system, recalculated to nm
    
# transforming mpmath.zeta to be compatible ith numpy:
    
    npzeta = np.frompyfunc(zeta,2,1)
    
# defining "sub-functions" for the final result

    zeta1 = npzeta(0.5, 0.5 + (lb**2)/(l**2))
    zeta2 = npzeta(0.5, 0.5 + (lb**2)/(lfi**2))
    zeta3 = npzeta(0.5, 0.5 + 4*(lb**2)/(lso**2)+(lb**2)/(lfi**2))

    return N*((q**2)/(4*np.pi*h*lb))*(2*zeta1 + zeta2 - 3*zeta3)
```

4. The parameter `f0`, which is passed to `np.isfinite()`, is defined as:

```
def fun_wrapped(x):
        return np.atleast_1d(fun(x, *args, **kwargs))
f0 = fun_wrapped(p0)
```

Since `p0` is just an array of floats or integers, it seems to me that the problem is that `fun_wrapped(p0)` gives an array of `mpmath`-type objects. Here are my questions:

1. What does `_wrap_func(func, xdata, ydata, transform)` actually do?
2. Why does `f0` contain `mpmath`-type objects, not floats?
3. Can I overcome this issue without making modifications to `least_squares` source code?
4. Why is the error present **only** when I pass `bounds` to `curve_fit`?

I tried to make this question as clear and concise as possible, but the issue seems to be quite complex - I am happy to provide more information or edit it if something is not clear.

Comment: `scipy` code often uses `c/fortran` functions that are only compiled for standard float types.  `mpmath` has its own extended precision numeric representation.  Pure `numpy` code may store `mpf` as `object` dtype, and do slow math with it.  Otherwise don't try to mix `scipy` and `mpmath`.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj for your comment. I've realized that `npzeta(0.5, x).astype(float)`, where `x = np.arange(0.01, 1, 0.1)` and `npzeta = np.frompyfunc(mpmath.zeta,2,1)`, returns array of 'normal' floats. However, if I try to do the same with my code (like `zeta1 = npzeta(0.5, 0.5 + (lb**2)/(l**2)).astype(float)`) I get the error: 'mpf' object has no attribute 'astype'. Any idea why?

Comment: if `lb` or `l` is a `mpf`, then passing it  through `npzeta` might return a `mpf` or array with `mpf` objects.  And hence the astype error.